# can i recover my mysql database from wamp?

Tags: php

I reinstalled window without taking backup of wamp folder.I only took backup of www directory but by god grace,even after reinstallation there is a wamp folder in my C drive .At this location **C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\data\mysql** ,I have .frm and .myd files .can i recover mydatabase from these files ?

Comment: databases are in `C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\data`. `C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\data\mysql` is `mysql` database only. If you can only see `mysql` and `test` folder in `data` folder, then I have a bad  news for you. `data` folder must have a folder with same name as your `database-name`.

Comment: I might suggest you to use undelete file tools (software) and try to recover you lost database files, then see if you can recover them some how using this tools or other similar tools http://www.en.mysqldatabaserecovery.net have never tried it before, but depends on your data value, it is may worth spending few minutes for find out if that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to say that your database is lost. MySQL creates a folder in the data directory named after the databases it contains. If there are no folders other than the default mysql folder, that indicates that there are no more databases.